# Why is CFSetGetValues clobbering the NSSet passed to it?

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I am trying to use `CFSetGetValues()` on an `NSSet` instance, but it seems to be clobbering the set's memory. Using a watchpoint, the set instance is being written to from `objc_assign_strongCast_non_gc()`. Right now, I haven't a clue as to what is going on.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, nil];
    const void *objects = calloc(set.count, sizeof(id));
    CFSetGetValues((__bridge CFSetRef)set, &objects);
    NSLog(@"Set %@", set); // *** set has been clobbered ***
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is on OS X 10.8, 64-bit. The same code fails when run in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my version of 10.8.4, nor the 6.1 iOS simulator.

Comment: @CodaFi that gets me even more confused. So the log statement prints out the entire set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `&` from `&objects` when calling `CFSetGetValues()`. Note that the `values` parameter is of type `const void **`, which means it’s an array (*) where each element is an arbitrary pointer (void *). Since `objects` is an array already, you do not need to obtain its address with the `&` operator.

It would make sense to use `&` if the array were allocated by the function, hence its address would have to be returned to the callee. That’s not the case, though, since you are responsible for allocating the array.

Comment: Also, I’m not sure why `-[NSSet getObjects:]` is not (public) API. `NSArray` and `NSOrderedSet` export `-getObjects:range:`, but `-[NSSet getObjects:]` is private.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is that `objects` should really be `const id *` and, since `id` is a pointer already, it is similar to `const void **`.

Comment: When I see `**` I always think of passing in something of the form `&pointer`, which as you say works for out arguments. I see now that because `id` is a pointer, the expression `calloc(set.count, sizeof(id))` non-obviously results in `**` and thus taking the address of that results in `***`.

Comment: Yes, I too was wondering why `NSSet` didn't have a `-getObjects:`.

Comment: `CFSetGetValues()` is none too happy when you remove the address-of operator, tho.  It's really too bad you have to do an unchecked cast to `void**`.